# Using the `showkeys` package adds two new pages after the `\part` page to show only the label key

Tags: parts, showkeys

The following example creates 5 pages. Page 1 contains the `\part`, page 3 only shows the `\part`'s `\label`, and page 5 shows the `\chapter`.
If I do not load `showkeys` then naturally, only 3 pages are created, the first for `\part` and the third for `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}
\part{First part}\label{part1}
\chapter{Chapter one}\label{chap1}
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to force the label shown for `\part` onto the same page as the `\part` itself so that no extra two pages are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Place the `\label` in the argument (which is safer for many things, not just `showkeys`)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}
\part{First part\label{part1}}
\chapter{Chapter one\label{chap1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's the first time in >10 years of using LaTeX that I heard that one can do it… Thanks for the rapid and helpful answer!